# Merge sort runs forever

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

I want to sort a 2d int array based on the 2nd element and this is what I came up with. But it doesnt seem to work. I understand there is a Arrays.sort(array, Comparator) which I can use, but I wanted to write my own sorting algorithm for the fun of it. Could anyone help me out please ?

ip = [[5,10],[2,5],[4,7],[3,9]]

Expected op = [[5,10],[3,9],[4,7],[2,5]]

```
void mergeSort(int[][] boxTypes){
    int mid = boxTypes.length / 2;
    int[][] left = new int[mid][2];
    int[][] right = new int[boxTypes.length - mid][2];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < mid; i++) left[i] = boxTypes[i];
    for(int i = mid; i < boxTypes.length; i++) right[i - mid] = boxTypes[i];
    
    mergeSort(left);
    mergeSort(right);
    
    merge(left, right, boxTypes);
}

void merge(int[][] left, int[][] right, int[][] boxTypes){
    int i = 0; int j = 0; int k = 0;
    
    while(i < left.length && j < right.length){
        if(left[i][1] < right[j][1]){
            boxTypes[k][0] = left[i][0];
            boxTypes[k][1] = left[i++][1];
        } else {
            boxTypes[k][0] = right[j][0];
            boxTypes[k][1] = right[j++][1];
        }
        k++;
    }
    
    while(i < left.length) boxTypes[k++] = left[i++];
    while(j < right.length) boxTypes[k++] = right[j++];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never stop the recursion:

- in the first step you split `boxTypes` into two arrays of length 2.
- in the second step you split the first array of length 2 into two arrays of length 1.
- in the third step you split the first array of length 1 into an array of length 0 and one of length 1.
- in the fourth (and every succeeding step) you try to split the array of length 0 into two arrays of length zero.

You need to stop the recursion as soon as the length of `boxTypes` is 1 or less (since an array of length 0 or 1 is trivially sorted):

```
void mergeSort(int[][] boxTypes){
    if (boxTypes.length <= 1) return;
    int mid = boxTypes.length / 2;
    int[][] left = new int[mid][2];
    int[][] right = new int[boxTypes.length - mid][2];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < mid; i++) left[i] = boxTypes[i];
    for(int i = mid; i < boxTypes.length; i++) right[i - mid] = boxTypes[i];
    
    mergeSort(left);
    mergeSort(right);
    
    merge(left, right, boxTypes);
}
```